# javascript canvas global.alpha precision

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm using the canvas to draw an image in JavaScript and I wanted to fade certain parts of the image. To do this I decided to use globalAlpha as I draw those parts, but I'm having trouble using numbers that are more than 1 number past the decimal point.

If I use 0.9 or 0.8 it works fine, but if i use 0.95, or 0.85 then there's no difference between 0.95 and 0.9, or 0.85 and 0.8. Is there anyway to achieve this type of precision?

Comment: Yes, changing globalAlpha (0.00-1.00) does not appear visually linear to the human eye. In your case you might have to change alpha in larger increments--especially around the upper and lower bounds of alpha. For example change the alpha from .95 to .85 instead of .95 to .90. So, humans==not so great at color differentiation. But on the bright side, birds have amazing color differentiation so your pet parrot will see even the slightest alpha change in your image. :-)

Comment: What do you mean, "there is no difference"? Did you read the drawn pixels back in, and their alpha channel byte is the same?

Comment: Agreed, the mathematical pixel values for alpha are linear--I'm not saying the browser is misbehaving. :-) But the human eye has trouble visualizing alpha differences.  Humans see green alpha color changes quite well, but have trouble with other colors--that's human evolution.

Comment: Ah, I think he might be right, I zoomed in really close and I think  I can see it change now